# What is this compost ingredient that looks like light colored pellets and crushes easily?

Tags: identification, compost

I and my colleague faced an unexpected problem during the mixing of a new compost ingredient today. We found an unexpected and unknown material left by a previous farm intern. We recognize the ingredient by the type of bag holding it, but apparently someone filled this bag with something other than what it normally holds. 
 Please see the photo:

[image: Unknown ingredient]

Another close-up image after spending half-day in a compost bin (slightly dissolved and contaminated with other compost ingredients)
[image]

Does anyone recognize what is it? It looks like some kind of hamster bedding to me, but I am not sure. Also, it does not have the smell of cat litter from my olfactory memory. It is easily crushed into a powdery substance.

Comment: It looks like some kind of hamster bedding to me but I am not sure.

Comment: Vaguely resembles pelletized grain (feed) I've fed to young dairy calves.

Comment: Thanks for the information! Our farm is small and do not raise animals, but it could be transported from elsewhere for the purpose of composting (not sure). I am asking previous intern, hope they know what it is.

Comment: Hi! If the previous intern or someone else is able to figure this out for you, the community would love to know. SE encourages people to [answer their own questions](http://gardening.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer), so feel free to write an answer when you have one. That way anyone who comes across this later will have all the information. Good luck!

Comment: @ Sue and everyone helping me, the previous intern and my boss have a not 100% certain answer up to this moment. It is likely to be pelleted chicken manure tranported from a nearby farm. My boss also mentioned it can be mouse bedding from labs, since another colleagues are working on related things. I need to wait for more answers from more colleagues and people involved before arriving at a conclusion. Everyone is enjoying holiday due to tropical cyclone in my home place, so I will need to wait some days before getting their reply. Thanks again for everyone's help.

Comment: Whatever it is, it is pelleted.  It must be either a food product or a wood product and those clumps do not look like kitty poo.  If it doesn't smell like kitty poo, it probably isn't.  Kitty poo is usually long and thinner.  Anything with moisture tossed into this pelletized stuff will clump up like this.  I'd relax and mix it into the rest of the compost.  If it is a bit of poo, NO BIG DEAL anyway.  The only compost that is controlled and TESTED with itemized constituents is HUMAN SEWAGE mixed with sawdust...a little high in heavy metals...it is beautiful and plants love this stuff.

Answer (score 10):

I think we are looking at wood pellets, the kind used for pellet stoves.  I use these same pellets for horse bedding, they are wonderful.  They are also used to compost solid sewage for those self contained composting toilets.  Yes, could be bedding for small animals, too, or cat boxes.

For my horses, I would poke a hole in a bag and fill it with water from a hose. Allow it to absorb the water for an hour or less and then dump to spread on the floor of a stall.  Lovely stuff.

It is nothing more than sawdust pressed together in little hard pellets.  Great for brown ingredients in your compost.

If the previous owner was using this for hamsters great.  For cat box litter not so great at all.  Cats eat meat.  Poop from omnivores and carnivores should never be mixed into compost.  High incidence of heavy metals and other stuff.

Answer (score 7):

That's what feed grain pellets look like once they start decomposing (after humidity affects it). I'm guessing that's what that is, probably grain that went too far to feed.

High protein content and some fat mean this is a valuable addition to a compost heap, but mix it thoroughly rather than have it in a pile, so that you get more bacterial action and less mold action (the bacteria is what fixes the nitrogen into the organic atter).

This is the shape the feed is in fresh from the mill (before decomposition starts):

[image]

Comment: Cool, J.!  Same color only made of 'grain'?